# Data Type that can be used to select Desktop as a folder in ArcGIS Python Toolbox (ArcGIS Desktop: ArcMap 10.6)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, python-script-tool, parameters, python-toolbox

I have created a Python Toolbox. While setting up my tool, in the parameters I am trying to find a data type to use in order to select Desktop as the location to create a folder.

I need to find a parameter to use to accept: `C:\Users\ME\Desktop`.

I have gone through many of these data types

[image]

Is there a data type that will accept Desktop as a folder in order to create a folder on the Desktop?

Comment: Parameter called Folder

Comment: Btw -1 from me. It came to my attention that you have 4 posts, each offering a solid solution and you didn't  bother to spend extra second of you time to accept any of them.

Comment: okay and.......

Answer (score 4):

Made it a minute ago, using Folder as type of parameter:

[image]
[image]